# Modify computer case to fit entrails?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata, power-management, storage-spaces

I've got a hardware question today.

My PC is currently at a state where it has too many parts outside the case for Its own good. You can see below that some of the external parts, which include power supplies and HDDs. (4 on top of the case).  Even though I have an external Power supply, my PC also has an internal power supply. The reason I use the external PSU is for additional SATA-type Power ports. The PSUs have a common-ground connection, so there is no need to worry about Over-Voltages.

[image]

*My question is as follows:* **How do I improve my space usage efficiency such that I can fit all of the hard disk drives In my PC with one PSU?**

My thoughts on how this could possibly be done:

- Get some SATA Y-Type power splitters, as the HDDs only use 8.84 Watts a piece on max load. This would eliminate the need for a second PSU.
- Physically remove the 5 Inch drive bays (which are empty at the moment) to make room for more 3.5 Inch bays.

Comment: What makes you think you need the external PSU in the first place?

Comment: "hysically remove the 5 Inch drive bays" - There exists modules that allow you to place multiple 3.5" disks into a single 5 inch bay.

Comment: @Ramhound read above: I don't have enough sata power ports.

Comment: That isn't a good reason to use multiple PSU.  You can purchase sata power cables that can be attached to multiple devices.  You can also simple use a PSU that has more SATA power cables.

Comment: @Ramhound at this time, I'm not willing to use much money to upgrade my PC. I'd say cables and bays are the upper limit to my budget. Looking for some DIY type advice, as well as some good practices tips.

Comment: Good luck to you.  I have many ideas but feel this question isn't well thought out, and i am getting the impression you don't want to hear the solutions I have.  If are not willing to spend money your problem cannot be solved IMO

Comment: @Ramhound You have an engineering degree. You know as well as I that there are many ways to solve this problem without money (albeit some better than others).